# Tratamento de dados

Tags: javascript

Estou recebendo em json um uma lista de categoria que tem os dados de id e nome.

Eu faço o restful em javascript puro e já consigo visualizar os dados no console do browser, estou usando este código:

```
   if (xhr.status == 200) {

    window.sessionStorage.setItem('lista', xhr.responseText);

    var lista = window.sessionStorage.getItem('lista');

    lista = JSON.parse(lista);

    let x = document.querySelector('#body')

    JSON.map(item => {

      x.innerHTML += '<tr><td>'+ item.title +'</td></tr>'
    });

}
```

O meu problema é que não sei como faço para inserir os dados que recebo em tabela para exibi-la aos usuários. Alguém pode pelo menos dizer a lógica ou me mostrar um exemplo de código se for possível?

Comment: está usando JS Puro?

Comment: Estou sim @RafaelAugusto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer é utilizando o `innerHTML` (não posso dizer que sejá a melhor forma).

Mas seria assim

```js
let json = [
  {title: 'Jobs'},
  {title: 'Mark'},
  {title: 'Bill'}
]


let x = document.getElementById('body')


json.map(item => {
  x.innerHTML += '<tr><td>'+ item.title +'</td></tr>'
})
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nomes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody id="body">
        
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Eu tentei aqui @RafaelAugusto, mas não funcionou. Diz que JSON.map não é uma função

Comment: Eu atualizei o código na minha pergunta. Coloquei usando o seu código

Comment: Coloquei lista.map ao invés de json,map e ele colocou as tabelas na tela, mas está escrito undefined no lugar dos valores. Mas parece que o número de tabelas que ele inseriu é a mesma quantidade de valores que existem na lista

Comment: Deu certo, valeu

Comment: @FrancisVagnerdaLuz Show,

Answer (score 0):

Vamos entender o problema. Segundo consta na documentação, [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) contém métodos para parsing *JSON* que são esses:

- [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Por esse motivo ao tentar executar o código `JSON.map(item => ...` ira retornar esse erro no *Console*:

> TypeError: JSON.map is not a function

Pois [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) não faz parte do objeto [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)